# Adding a dynamic Active Admin utility dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am new to Active Admin and am trying to add a dynamic utility dropdown menu like this:

```
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu do |menu|
      menu.add label: "Company", priority: 1 do |company|
          company.add label: "ABC Company", url: "/admin/?company=abc"
          company.add label: "XZY Company", url: "/admin/?company=xyz"
      end
    end
  end
```

I have a `Company` model with a `name` (ABC Company) and `tenant_name` (abc) so I want to loop through the Companies and dynamically generate this menu.  I have played with a few guesses but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can dynamically create a menu of companies that redirect to their respective edit pages. Don't forget you need to restart your server to see these changes.

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add label: "Companies", priority: 1 do |company|
      Company.all.each do |existing_company|
        company.add label: existing_company.name, url: "/admin/companies/#{existing_company.id}/edit"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I figured it was something like that.  I was trying a few variations of that.  The nesting of `company` inside `existing_company` is not obvious.

Comment: This work only once. If we add new company, the menu does not refresh.